# Analytic continuation of $ F(k)=\bigg|\int_0^1 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}}{x\log^k(x)}~dx \bigg|=(k-2)! $

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, gamma-function, analytic-continuation

$$ F(k)=\bigg|\int_0^1 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}}{x\log^k(x)}~dx \bigg|=(k-2)! $$ for $\Re(k)\ge2. $

> Can you analytically continue $F(k)?$ If so, how?

I was reading about the Gamma function and how it is defined by a convergent integral, which is subsequently analytically continued using complex analysis. I tried fiddling around with the integral and looked for a substitution to change it into the Gamma function but didn't succeed.

Comment: Won't the substitution $u=-1/\log(x)$ lead back to the gamma function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll do it in several steps for clarity, but you can do it in one fell swoop if you like.

Let $z=\log(x)$. Then $dz=dx/x$ and the new limits of integration are $-\infty,0$:
$$
\bigg|\int_0^1 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}}{x\log^k(x)}~dx \bigg|
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \bigg|\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}}}{z^k}~dz \bigg|
$$Now let $1/z=t$ or $z=1/t$:
$$
\Rightarrow \bigg|\int_{0}^{-\infty} {e^{t}}t^{k-2}\,dt \bigg|
$$Lastly, put $y=-t$ to get rid of the absolute values (for $k>1$):
$$
\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty} {e^{-y}}y^{k-2}\,dy=\Gamma(k-1)
$$